# Basic c# array printing

Tags: c#, arrays, object, printing, abstract

I managed to get the program to accept values but I'm not quite sure how to print my results, when i tried to print it like this, which is wrong, it just gave me random text. I guess it should be something like sh.display or something but i'm really lost here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    abstract class shape
    {
        void getarea()
        { Console.WriteLine("Area is"); }
        void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is shape");
        }   
        void getcirc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Circumference is");
        }
    }

    class circle : shape
    {
       public circle(double r)
       {this.r = r;}
        double r;
        void getarea()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Circle area =" + (Math.PI * Math.Pow(r, 2)));
        }

        void getcirc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Circle circumference = " + (2 * Math.PI * r));
        }

        void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is circle");
        }
    }

    class rect : shape
    {
        public rect(double x, double y)
        {this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }
        double x,y;
        void getarea()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rectangle area =" + (x * y));
        }

        void getcirc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Circle circumference = " + ((2 * x) + (2 * y)));
        }

        void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is Rectangle");
        }

        class square : shape
        {
            public square(double z)
            {this.z=z;
            }
            double z;
            void getarea()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Square area =" + (z*z));
            }

            void getcirc()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Square perimeter = " + (4 * z));
            }

            void display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is square");
            }




            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    shape[] sh = new shape[15];
                    Random rndm= new Random();

                    int i;
                    int shapenum;
                    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                    { shapenum = rndm.Next(1,4);

                    switch (shapenum)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter radius");
                            sh[i] = new circle(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                            break;

                        case 2:

                            Console.WriteLine("Enter x and y lengths");
                            double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            sh[i] = new rect(x,y);
                            break;

                        case 3:

                            Console.WriteLine("Enter side length");
                            sh[i] = new square(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                            break;
                    }
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(sh[i] + " ");
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "gave me random text"...

Comment: ConsoleApplication1.rect ConsoleAppication1.rect CosnoleApplication1.circle ConsoleApplication1.Circle ConsoleApplication1.rect+square

Comment: That's not random. That's exactly what it's supposed to print. Try replacing `Console.Write(sh[i] + " ");` with `sh[i].display();`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Oh, I'm supposed to enter 15 random elements(one of the three shapes) then use a loop to print each element's data (Area, circumference/perimeter and type) using the three methods (Display, getarea and getcirc) in each class.
Also it said shape.display() is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Just make all the classes and functions public to get access to them. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your classes override `.ToString()`, so when you call `Console.Write(sh[i] + " ")` it's just printing the type name of the object. (Not "random text".)

You need to do one of two things:

1. Define a `.ToString()` override on your classes (easiest, recommended);
2. Make `shape.display()` a `virtual` method (`virtual void display()`) and use `override void display()` in all sub-classes, then call `sh[i].display()` instead of `Console.Write(sh[i] + " ")`;

Either one will fix your issue.

Of course, if the goal is to make `getarea()` and `getcirc()` on all classes derived from `shape`, then you should be marking them `virtual` on `shape` and then marking them `override` on sub-classes.

Better yet, replace `shape` with an `interface` (`IShape`) and then make all the sub-classes simply *implement* the interface.

Comment: `sh[i].display()` is not going to work. Shape is a abstract class

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Console.Write(sh[i] + " ")` will output the object reference into the console because `shape` is a reference type, or in simple words, an object, and not a primitive/value type. This is the output that is the "random text" you are talking about.

Now comes the question of what you want to display for your purposes. If you want to simply display "This is a square" or "This is a circle", you will have to call the display function using 
`Console.Write(sh[i].display() + " ")`

Similarly, you may want to call `sh[i].getcirc()` or `sh[i].getarea()` for printing the circumference and area.

Comment: After entering 15 random elements(circle or rectangle or square) using a loop I'm supposed to use another loop to print each element's data (Area, circumference/perimeter and type) using the three methods but It's not letting me use sh[i].getcirc because shape is an abstract class,

Comment: You should declare `class Program` and `class Square` outside `class rect` like `class Circle`. At the moment, they are nested within each other and hence your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code and fixed the issue. Key moments:

- Use abstract/override words for methods.
- Overridden ToString() for base class
- Follow C# naming conventions

Here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  abstract class Shape
  {
    public abstract string GetArea();
    public abstract string Display();
    public abstract string GetPerimeter();
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return Display() + ": " + GetArea() + ", " + GetPerimeter();
    }
  }

  class Circle : Shape
  {
    public Circle(double r)
    {
      this.r = r;
    }

    double r;

    public override string GetArea()
    {
      return "Circle area =" + Math.PI*Math.Pow(r, 2);
    }

    public override string GetPerimeter()
    {
      return "Circle circumference = " + 2*Math.PI*r;
    }

    public override string Display()
    {
      return "This is Circle";
    }
  }

  class Rect : Shape
  {
    public Rect(double x, double y)
    {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    double x, y;

    public override string GetArea()
    {
      return "Rectangle area =" + x*y;
    }

    public override string GetPerimeter()
    {
      return "Circle circumference = " + (2*x + 2*y);
    }

    public override string Display()
    {
      return "This is Rectangle";
    }
  }

  class Square : Shape
  {
    public Square(double z)
    {
      this.z = z;
    }

    double z;

    public override string GetArea()
    {
      return "Square area =" + z*z;
    }

    public override string GetPerimeter()
    {
      return "Square perimeter = " + 4*z;
    }

    public override string Display()
    {
      return "This is Square";
    }

  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var sh = new Shape[15];
      var rndm = new Random();

      for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
      {
        switch (rndm.Next(1, 4))
        {
          case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter radius");
            sh[i] = new Circle(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            break;
          case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter x and y lengths");
            double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sh[i] = new Rect(x, y);
            break;
          case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter side length");
            sh[i] = new Square(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            break;
        }
      }

      foreach (var shape in sh)
        Console.WriteLine(shape);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```